# How to estimate/compute for disconnected neutral potential rise?

Tags: distribution-network

This is a different question, I want to know what could be the minimum distances between poles before the ungrounded neutral in one pole can create different potential from the other neutrals in other poles. If they are close like 30 meters apart, maybe the neutral with removed ground rod is as good as fully grounded??

As illustration. Supposed you have 3 distribution poles (from 13,000 volts primary to 120/240v secondary single split phase supplying American houses).

[image: 1]

And one of the poles lost the connection of its centertap neutral to the ground by the pole grounding wire disconnected from the ground rod accidentally  (note I'm describing the US power system). What would be the potential of that floating neutral when all the other poles neutral are connected together (With other poles centertap still connected to their corresponding ground rods)?

Comment: You have asked a series of questions on this topic. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: In my clubhouse. I'm only using 240v 2-pole service in the US power system. This is to avoid broken neutral and all metal chassis electrified so I avoid 120v. I'm also using GFCIs. However, I need to know whether the panel enclosure needs to be connected to the service neutral which I never use. But looking at the pole ground rod. It can easily get disconnected.When this happens, and I touch the panel enclosure, It's like I'm directly touching the disconnected neutral in the pole. Would I get a shock when this event happened? If there is real hazard. Then I'd just build a live enclosure alarm.

Comment: I'm not following everything you're saying here, but it sounds like a code violation, especially if your "clubhouse" is open to the public. You need to ask these questions on [DIY.SE](https://diy.stackexchange.com/), explaining exactly what you're doing and what your concerns are. (BTW, metal enclosures should NEVER be connected to neutral, only to ground. Neutral should be bonded to ground at the service entrance ONLY.)

Comment: I'm building a circuit that can tell if panel enclosure is energized by the hot accidentally touching it. I know neutral should never be connected to metal. But if the service entrance neutral got disconnected. The metal chasis would become path to the 120v electricity. Hence I don't  use 120v. Anyway. Please just tell me.  What would happen if the centertaps of different poles are connected in your neighborhood?

Comment: You MUST use the neutral, and provide 120 circuits, if you want to use the 120V lamps and appliances that are used in North America.  The power company's ground/neutral wire is (or should be) grounded at each pole transformer, and at each customer's service entrance.  In your drawing, there should be no significant voltage between your broken ground wilre and the grounds at the other poles.

Comment: So in essence, there would be nothing wrong if you connect all the centertap neutral together in a street in North America?  Or can it cause a short? Not that I'd do it, of course I couldn't in the first place because it is the power utility that do it. But I have really seen many centertap neutrals connected together, any hidden side effects?

Comment: In my area (Vancouver BC) the center tap of the 120/240V distribution transformer secondarys are all connected together by the power company, and connected to a ground rod at each transformer, and at each customer's service entrance.  This Ground/Neutral connection also serves as the 13.2 KV High Voltage return wire, so must continue all the way back to the local power substation.

Comment: Does Canada have the same power system as the United States?

Comment: The US and Canada both use the "split-phase" 120/240V system for domestic customers.  I expect (but have no direct knowledge) that the overall power distribution systems are very similar - power is shared between the US and Canada in some areas, so there must be some compatibility. However,  I'm sure there are some minor variations in electrical code requirements between the various states and provinces.

Answer (score 2):

The pole transformer secondary windings are completely independent from each other. There is no pole-to-pole connection of the neutrals like you show in your drawing.

Therefore, there is no benefit at all from nearby transformers if any particular transformer secondary becomes ungrounded.

Comment: But I have actually seen poles with all the secondary neutral lines connected together. What would be wrong if this occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you saw, but it wasn't this. Perhaps you saw three transformers on a single pole -- that would be how 3-phase power is delivered to a customer.

Comment: No. I really saw all the poles with the centertap connected together. I can even take picture tom and show you. Why. What would happen if you do this? We didn't use the neutral in the centertapped for 120v.

Comment: In my area (Vancouver BC), the centertap output from the pole transformer is also the High Voltage return, and is connected to a continuous ground/neutral wire that connects the center taps of all transformers together, and presumably runs all the way back to a substation.  This ground/neutral wire is connected to a ground rod at each transformer, and at each customer's service entrance.

Comment: Peter. Please read this since you are from Canada https://www.labour.gov.on.ca/english/hs/pubs/alerts/a04.php  how come when the connection to the ground rod was disconnected and the utility man touched the neutral and ground plate, he burnt his hands?

Comment: If the system is 4 wire (i.e. wye) then there is a neutral wire that connects all the distribution transformers, and this neutral is bonded to ground at each transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Dave is incorrect above. In Canada and USA the 120/240 V transformer neutrals are each connected to the primary power system neutral which is shared with the secondary network. The multi-grounded neutral design provides good safety due to the parallel impedance of all the different grounds. This includes both power system grounds and grounds at customer service entrances. In Canada, the parallel neutral/ground return path must be less than 6 ohms at any point in the power system according to CSA. Though this level is actually quite high, a good-performing system with low impedance ground rods might be less than 1 ohm. I have found that 2 ohms is fairly typical. So the worst case scenario for someone touching a ground wire, or bonded equipment, is when the power system has a primary fault to ground. Imagine, for example, a 3000 A ground fault, passing through the neutral/grounding system impedance of 2 ohms. It's easy to see with basic Ohm's law that the neutral system will experience a voltage rise of 6000 V at the point of the fault. As current finds it way though all the ground rods, the voltage rise tapers off. So it tapers off quickly within a dense urban area having lots of grounds rods, and more slowly in a rural area. There is some risk to a person it they simultaneously contact a ground wire and close a path to ground. But keep in mind a human body is around 1000 ohms of resistance, so contacting a ground wire of much small resistance will not actually cause a huge amount of current to pass through you. Of course this is not absolute, there are some situations that are more dangerous, like contacting a broken neutral and working in substations. So don't be touching system grounds ;-)

Comment: If, as in your example, wire to ground is 2Ω
 and human to ground is 1000Ω, then 1/500 of the current through the wire will pass through the human. If, again, using your figures, 3000 A is going through wire. That would mean 3000/500 = 6A would be passing through the human. Certainly not "so contacting a ground wire of much small resistance will not actually cause a huge amount of current to pass through you."

Comment: 3000 A is the fault current passing through the multi-grounded neutral (MGN) system and 2 Ω is the total resistance of the system. Fault current splits between thousands of ground rods in varying proportions, according on their resistances and proximity. A fraction of this current goes through 1 ground rod that a person might touch, perhaps 5 A for example. That ground rod is maybe 100 Ω so the split will be different. Say 5 A / 10 = 0.5 A which sounds small, but can be dangerous. The saving grace is that protection is sensitive in MGN and the fault should be cleared in 6-15 cycles.